# PHP Ranking/autonumbering

Tags: php, rank

I just want to have an auto numbering in rank since the data in the table is ordered based from the total.

```
NAME | TOTAL | RANK

ABC   | 15    | 1

DEF  | 12    | 2

GHI  | 11    | 3
```

Comment: What code generates this? What have you tried? We know your problem, now give us some context that will let us help you.

Comment: Given that this looks like it'll be pulling from e.g. mysql, you should be able to get rank generated with the SQL query.

Comment: `order by total desc`? But what do you want for rank when two or more records have equal total?